# ScrollView and touch events not working together in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I have a screen in which I have scrollable boxlayout. It works fine and I can scroll through the labels, text inputs and buttons inside the screen

```
 #kvfile
<FirstScreen>:
    ScrollView:
        BoxLayout:
            orientation:"vertical"
            size_hint_y: None 
            height: self.minimum_height  
            #here some scrollable labels, text inputs, and buttons

#python file
class FirstScreen(Screen):
    '''
    initial = 0
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        self.initial = touch.x

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        if touch.x > self.initial:
            # do something
        elif touch.x < self.initial:
            # do other thing
        else: 
            # what happens if there is no move
    '''
    pass
```

But when I added a touch event to detect right and left swipe the scroll become disabled. Now I can do left,right swipes but not scrolling. How to enbable both scrolling as well as swipe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are interrupting the [event bubbling](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.widget.html?highlight=widget#widget-touch-event-bubbling) with this code, and the `on_touch_down` methods of the children of the layout are not called at all. Generally you should always either return `True` or pass on the event (or some combination of the two).

```
class FirstScreen(Screen):
    initial = 0
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        self.initial = touch.x
        return super(Screen, self).on_touch_down(touch) #pass the touch on

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        if touch.x > self.initial:
            print "left"
            return True #don't pass the touch on
        elif touch.x < self.initial:
            print "right"
            return True
        else: 
            print "no"
            return super(Screen, self).on_touch_up(touch)
```

Comment: The current solution works but partially. I am developing this in my computer, it looks like the scroll only works when we use mouse's scroll button and we cant scroll it by touch.

Comment: could be because when scrolling by touch you are still changing the `x` coordinate unintentionally and then the conditions kick in and kill the event. You need some way to distinguish when the user *wants* to swipe or scroll, and then `return True` or pass the event on. (or you could always pass the event if they don't conflict somehow). For example you can set some minimum distance for the swipe `if abs(touch.x - self.initial) > X`...

Comment: This is the condition I am using for scrolling left and right `p=(touch.x-self.initial)/self.initial` and I have added a threshold to detect left and right swipe. I think scrollview has enabled but my touch event is overiding scrollview's touch. I need some way to enable scrollview's touch when swiped up and down. I have no idea how to do that. I can use this `p=(touch.y-self.initial)/self.initial` to detect up/down swipe but how to enable scrollview touch

Comment: I don't know what's going on there - I re-ran the code from the answer, and I can scroll the result with left-click drag. Could it be some other widget eating up the event? also the last line in my code was wrong (it was passing(`on_touch_down` of `on_touch_up`; updated 2 lines)

Comment: thanks it worked the updated code worked. Its really a pain in the a** when some thing dosent work :). Once more thank you